# Flutter - How to run fetch data only once?

Tags: flutter, api, async-await

I,

I have a widget local state and have `initState()` hook to fetch external data.

Code is here:

```
void initState() {
    if (_modulesData.length < 1) {
      print("i fetch");
      FetchModules().fetchAllModules().then((res) {
        setState(() {
          _modulesData = res;
          _isLoaded = !_isLoaded;
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        setState(() {
          _serverIsDown = !_serverIsDown;
          _showDialog(context);
        });
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

I tried to fetch data only once, if is `modulesData` array empty, but thinks not working, I get to print as result every time when I enter on the widget with that API call.

How I can fetch data only one? Per widget (page)? :)

Thank you. I am a Flutter newbie.

Comment: @pskink if you use that within the Widget, it will only exist for the lifecycle of the Widget right? I think the issue here is mostly because the Widget gets destroyed and he expects the state to still be there when he opens the page again (and creates a new Widget). OP probably needs to learn about [State management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Comment: Learn state management